# rails active record object in application controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm adding a site-wide form for asking questions on a rails site. The models/views/controllers for the resource **question** are already created. Going to question/new shows the form as you'd expect. Now I want to display a site-wide question form (the only difference with this one is that it only shows mandatory fields). Question: should I create a new question object in application_controller and pass that to the rails **form_for** helper, or should I create a new **_form2** partial(in the question view) and just include that in my site-wide template?

Thank you.

Comment: choice questions on stack overflow?

Comment: @DileepNandanam Not sure what you're referring to. Can you clarify? Do you mean whether I'm doing something like SA? I'm not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `question_form` partial in the `views/shared` folder, and reference that from the site wide template.

Edit: in reply to where to get the @question variable from

You have two options in my mind, you can load the variable in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :load_question

  def load_question
    @question = Question.new
  end

  ...

end
```

(You should be careful of conflicts with the @question variable in this case)

Or probably better, you can create a method in ApplicationHelper:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def question_form

    question = Question.new

    raw render 'shared/question_form', :question => question
  end

  ...
end
```

Then in your view, instead of referencing the partial, you reference the helper:

```
<%= question_form %>
```

In this case you would need to reference the variable in the partial as a local variable, so `question` instead of `@question`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Where will that partial get the @question object?